# Drawing specific diagonals in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to conduct and draw specific a sort of line by using PictureBox graphics

Here's my vision:

[image: diagonals]

and here's what I have tried so far:

```
//int nx = 9, ny = 9;
float dx = (float)PictureBox.Width / 8;
float dy = (float)PictureBox.Height / 5;

int x1 = 0;
int y1 = 1;
int x2 = 1;
int y2 = 0;

//Pen Paint Stlye
PenBlack.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid;

//0 < (9 + 9)
while (y1 < (9 + 9))
{
    g.DrawLine(PenBlack, x1 * dx, y1 * dy, x2 * dx, y2 * dy);
    y1++;
    x2++;
}
```

But out of this I am getting:

[image: output]

Essentially I want it to be exact and even on PictureBox size change.

Comment: Can you clarify? What does "I want it to be exact" mean? Both screenshots look very similar.

Comment: well if you look at the second one, the diagonals dont align EXACTLY into the square corners like in the first one.

Comment: @Charleh The ends of the diagonals do not touch the grid intersections in the second picture, but they do in the first.

Comment: More details needed: Is the picture box fixed in size? Is the number of grid squares parameterised or fixed? Are the grid squares actually square?

Comment: If you count your lines you have 8. Did you try setting it to 9? If that works then it's simply a case of ensuring you subdivide your grid up into the same number of bits as your line drawing algorithm. If you think about it, you want to draw a diagonal that touches the top right corner in each square (ignoring verticality) so surely you need as many lines as there are squares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply the grid was wrong.
I added 2 global variables:

```
int nx = 12, ny = 10;
```

NX being how many squares are on the X-axis

and NY being how many squares are on the Y-Axis

essentially this goes along with my grid code:

```
 //Divide WIDTH x Axis int 3 columns
        int x1 = TAPBxCanvas.Width / 2;

        //Divide HEIGHT y Axis into 3 rows;
        int y1 = TAPBxCanvas.Height / 2;

        //Find the Second point


        Point width = new Point(x1,y1);

        // - - -

        float dx = (float)TAPBxCanvas.Width / nx;
        float dy = (float)TAPBxCanvas.Height / ny;
        PenGray.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid;

        for (int ix = 0; ix <= nx; ix++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(PenGray, ix * dx, 0, ix * dx, TAPBxCanvas.Height);
        }

        for (int iy = 0; iy <= ny; iy++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(PenGray, 0, iy * dy, TAPBxCanvas.Width, iy * dy);
        }
```

added a new float value to the diagonals, dividing the Y squares to 2 so diagonals will overlap 2 squares :

```
float DnY = ny / 2;
```

and divided the height with the result of DnY:

```
float dy = (float)TAPBxCanvas.Height / DnY);
```

everything else stays the same and i get this:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVVs7.png)

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
float dx = (float)PictureBox.Width / 9.0f;
float dy = (float)PictureBox.Height / 4.5f;
```

As you got 9x9 squares and want 1x2 square slopes ... so `dx = xs/(9/1)` and `dy = ys/(9/2)`

Comment: I understand but as I inserted it i didn't get the outcome I was looking for rather this : https://imgur.com/a/Ha3H6

After a little tinkering a figured out it wasn't the diagonals that were wrong rather the grid behind em so i got it fixed. Thanks for the help though